# Facebook realtime updates: Subscribing to a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Anyone tried subscribing to a page for real-time updates? I would like to get notified when a new wall post appears under a page's feed for example.

The Facebook documentation says this is possible but have never seen anyone accomplished this before.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the page_accesstoken and then add the app as a tab. You can do this by
getting the user access token of the admin with scope=manage_pages
once you get the user access token you can query me/accounts. It will display something like

```
  {
      "category": "Community", 
      "name": "page name", 
      "access_token": "xxxxx", 
      "id": "1111111134678999", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }
```

That xxx would be the page access token, with the page access token you have to add your app as a tab. You can do that by

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/tabs?app_id=APPID&method=POST&access_token=xxx

And now you will get a request to your callback url whenever there is a change in the page. The request looks something like.

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "408518775908252",
            "time": 1360643280,
            "changes": [
                {
                    "field": "feed",
                    "value": {
                        "item": "like",
                        "verb": "add",
                        "user_id": 5900878
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Once you subscribe to realtime updates from page objects, you will get notifications only from **pages which have added your app** to themselves.

Much like you only get notifications from users who've auth'd your app, adding an application to a page as a tab is the equivalent of the page authing your app.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ on how to add an app to a page.

Comment: Does the app need to be added as a tab? I have already added an app to my page but it does not have a separate tab.

Comment: Yes, it has to be added as a tab.

Comment: You don't have to have it added as a tab, just installed via page/tabs edge. As the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/tabs/) states, it is not needed to configure the app as a Page tab app in the App Dashboard. If it is not configured, the app will only be installed for the Page and not added as a tab. This is useful if you are subscribing to real-time updates from the Page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  $my_access_token = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .$fbconfig['appid'] ."&client_secret=" .$fbconfig['secret'] ."&type=client_cred"); 
  // SUBSCRIBE!   
  $subscribe = array( 'access_token'=> substr($my_access_token,13),
                      'object' => 'user',
                      'fields' => 'name,feed',
                      'callback_url' => $fbconfig['callback'], 
                      'verify_token' => $fbconfig['secret']);
  $subscribe = $facebook->api("/" .$fbconfig['appid'] ."/subscriptions", 'post', $subscribe);
  $parameters =  array("access_token" => substr($my_access_token,13) );
  $results = $facebook->api('/' .$fbconfig['appid'] .'/subscriptions', $parameters); 
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
  error_log($e);
}
```