# Subscribe to facebook page feed real time updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a facebook app in Scala and Play!. I want real time updates for user feed and feed of pages this user administers, so I subscribed to those. This is what comes back from GET /{my_app_id}/subscriptions:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "object": "user", 
    "callback_url": "***", 
    "fields": [
      "feed"
    ], 
    "active": true
  }, 
  {
    "object": "page", 
    "callback_url": "***", 
    "fields": [
      "feed"
    ], 
    "active": true
  }
  ]
}
```

My server receives updates about the feed of the user that uses my app (including when he posts on his page's wall as himself), but no updates about posts made by the page he administers. The application is granted read_stream, user_status and manage_pages permissions. The question is can I get page feed updates without having the user add my app as a tab to his page? My app is not meant to be used as a tab app.

Short survey to show I actually did my homework:
[here](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/574604359287685/) the support engineer says it is possible, although it is unclear how to "use a Page Access Token tied to the both the Page and app when creating the subscription". 
On the other hand, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356869/facebook-realtime-updates-subscribing-to-a-page#comment22997243_8357237) CBroe says one has to add app as a tab. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384450) Caroline suggests to create a tab and delete it immediately, which looks ugly. I tried to add my app as a tab without prompting the user, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall#comment19783069_9909616), with the Graph API Explorer and got "Application does not have permission for this action".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The truth lies in the middle: one has to make a POST to https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/tabs?app_id=appId&access_token=page_access_token to get real time updates for the page, but this does not seem to add an app as a tab, the app just shows up among added apps in page settings. I did the POST through Graph API explorer to debug my update processing code, and the updates get to the server OK.

Comment: Yeah, Facebook is like that.

Comment: I try to do this POST call but I get this message: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action". What permission I need? Thanks!

Comment: @Gaucho_9, most likely, your app did not request manage_pages permission.

Comment: @Yar, yes, I request did permission, but not working. Should I configure app to be visible in App Center?? I have teh subscriptions okey for my app, and the permission too. When user update his feed I get the notifications. The last thing I need it's get the notifications for page update. What I need to configure to make this POST call accessible?

Comment: @Gaucho_9, make sure your app is subscribed to both user and page updates through /<appId>/subscriptions endpoint. I get the same error message if I provide an invalid access token in a POST request, so also verify that you are using an access token for the page you are subscribing to.

Comment: @Yar, thanks!!! Finally, I get realtime notifications with this method!!! You were right, my page access token doesn't correct! It's a bit confusing get realtime notifications for pages... Thanks a lot! ;-)

Comment: Can you please share the code for making subscription?

Comment: @Yar, that was really awesome, you made my day, was really struggling since last week, finally got the solution..!!!

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Comment: @RAJ Un-freakin'-believable! After all these months this question and answer still remain the main source of the information on the subject? Has facebook never updated their docs?

Comment: @Yar Frankly speaking, I didn't found fb docs much useful and informative in this context. It was too difficult to work with it. That's why I have documented whole thing in my blog: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Comment: I get a `App must have profile tab URL set` when I try to POST to the `/tabs` endpoint