# Real time updates from facebook page not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I saw a post on [Subscribe to facebook page feed real time updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189046/subscribe-to-facebook-page-feed-real-time-updates/30603867#30603867)

I have the same problem. But in the comment there is a solution and that is to make a post to https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/tabs?app_id=appId&access_token=page_access_token
But when I post it in my browser it shows some data. I am unable to understand how this url helps to get real time updates and how to use it.
This I have got after subscription completed:
        {
           "data": [
              {
                 "object": "page",
                 "callback_url": "http://www.i4mass.com/demo/fb.php",
                 "fields": [
                    "feed"
                 ],
                 "active": true
              }
           ]
        }

Which means the subscription is OK. 
This is my callback.php code:

```
    <?php
    define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'myString');                                    
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];                             

    if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' &&                 $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {

       echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
    } else if ($method == 'POST') {

       if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'] ) ) {
        $post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'] == "sha1=" . hash_hmac('sha1', $post_body, VERIFY_TOKEN)) {

            $object = json_decode($post_body, true);

            foreach($object->entry as $update)
            {

                file_put_contents('updates.txt', $update, FILE_APPEND);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```